# Relationship between three variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, relations

I have three variables $r$, $p$, and $ w$. The $w$ is weight, $r$ is distance, and $p$ is the number of people. Morover, I have $$r = aw^b,~~p = ae^{bw}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Given a value of $r$ and $p$, what is the way to calculate $w$ per unit distance per unit people?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

To make the question clearer:

I have a whole set of data for $r$, $p$, and $w$. I've plotted two scatter-plot graphs, one for $r$ vs $w$ and another for $p$ vs $w$. The above equations are the trendlines for the plots. I want to know if given a value of $r$ and $p$, is it possible to use the trendlines to estimate the value of $w$?

Comment: Do you mean "given values of $r$ and $p$..". As it reads now there is no reference to $q$ in your set-up. Also you should make it clear whether you just want $w$ or some kind of derivative of it, suggested by "per unit distance per unit people", but it's not immediately clear from the wording that you want a derivative, and if so what derivative.)

Comment: Sorry. That should be p. I'll edit the question to make it more clearer

Comment: I don't know if I should use derivatives or not. I tried rearranging both equations to make w the subject. Take their derivatives. Plug my values of r and p into them. Then multiply them together. Got an amazingly large value which couldn't be right.

Comment: @l3utterfly Can you estimate $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit2:

You know $b$ and you have $$r = aw^b,~~p = ae^{bw}.$$

Your question is "Given a value of $r$  and $p$ , what is the way to calculate $w$  per unit distance per unit people?"

Thus given particular values $R$ and $P$ you need to calculate $W$ which fits $R$ and $P$ (i.e. $W, R, P$ must satisfy your equations).  Then divide $W$ by $R P$ to get weight per unit distance per unit people.

If you divide your formulae for $r$ and $p$ you get

$$\frac{r}{p} = \frac{aw^b}{ae^{bw}} = \left( \frac{w}{e^w} \right)^b.$$

For a given $R$, $P$ you want to find $W$ for which it is true that

$$\frac{R}{P} = \left( \frac{W}{e^{W}} \right)^b.$$

Subtracting $\frac{R}{P}$ from both sides of this equation you want to find $W$ for which it is true that $$\left( \frac{W}{e^{W}} \right)^b - \frac{R}{P} = 0.$$

In other words, you have to find

$$W = x: f(x) = 0$$ where
$$f(x) = \left( \frac{x}{e^x} \right)^b - \frac{R}{P}.$$

You can find $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$ numerically, e.g. via [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

When you have $W$ you can get weight per unit distance per unit people = $\frac{W}{R P}$.

Comment: Brilliant idea... b is a constant I already know. You've got me thinking. So this gives distance per people. How would I go from there? I need to find weight per distance per people...

Comment: @l3utterfly Have edited to show one way to find $w$.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind explaining the principles behind this? I'll mark it as an answer then. Thanks again.

Comment: @l3utterfly Principles behind which bit?

Comment: I mean, why use the ratio of the trendlines then minus r over p. When that equals zero, why then would w be the weight per distance per people?

Comment: @l3utterfly It wouldn't, but $w/rp$ would.  Have edited again

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Sorry for being a bit slow :) +1 and marked as answer.